# Must type template every time for generic functions?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

In C++, is there any way to avoid having to type the template name every time I am writing a class function outside of its class definition?

For example, if I want to define a class function, do I have to type type `template <class T>` before every single function?  It seems like a lot of unnecessary work if I've already specified that the class uses a template.

For example...

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFirst(T data) {
//my code...
}
```

Why do I have to type `template <class T>` when I've already specified that LinkedList uses a generic?  I'm used to how generics work in Java so this is new to me.

Comment: Why not define the functions inside the class?

Comment: In C++ there are partial and explicit specializations of templates, therefore you have to write that `template <class T>` before every definition of a class member outside the class definition. E.g. `template <> void LinkedList<int>::addFirst(int data) {/*...*/}`

Comment: Oh, because I read that functions defined within a class are inline and usually should not be too large.

Comment: That's true (they're `inline` implicitly), but `inline` does not mean that they're inlined; you can define them outside the class because it may be better readable, but it's a bit more convenient to do it inside the class. For class templates, you have to (with exceptions) provide the definition of the member functions in the header, so you cannot put them in a source file (.cpp) like with ordinary classes (where that can speed up compilation).

Comment: @Duncan, inline is rather a request to the compiler. It is upto the compiler to decide whether a function should be inlined or not.

Comment: @Arun Some say it's even less than that: it's just a way to circumvent ODR, which doesn't apply (applies in another way) to anything related to templates.

Comment: Ah, so for classes where I use templates/generics, I should write the function definitions inside the class?

Comment: *should* is something that's open for discussion. It's up to you; AFAIK you have no disadvantage doing so (in class **templates**!) but slightly worse readability (like in Java ;)

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

Comment: @Duncan Template definitions are inline anyway (otherwise they would break ODR); so it makes no difference whether you define them inside or outside the class definition.

Comment: Just to drive in what Konrad said, templates are *always* `inline`; there is absolutely no way to get a non-`inline` function template because it's an essential part of how templates work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Only if you use `inline` in a broader sense. The ODR has an explicit exception for templates, [basic.def.odr]/6 "There can be more than one definition of a [..] member function of a class template [...]". They're not always `inline` in the sense of the keyword `inline`.

Comment: Why not either deing a hot key or use copy'n'paste

Answer (score 2):

```
//release 1:
template <class T>
struct LinkedList
{
    void addFirst(T data);
};

//release 2: partial specialization 
template <class T>
struct LinkedList<T*>
{
    void addFirst(T data);
};

//release 1: 
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFirst(T data) {}

//release 2
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T*>::addFirst(T data) {}

//complier could not tell which release
//void LinkedList::addFirst(T data){}

void main(){

    LinkedList<char> lc;
    lc.addFirst('c');

    LinkedList<char*> li;
    li.addFirst('c');
}
```